# Upload videos to youtube with javascript and without signing in to google

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-javascript-api

I want to allow visitors of my site to upload videos to my YouTube channel.

I don't want to force the visitors to sign in with Google.

I want the upload to be sent from the visitors browser directly to YouTube using CORS or similar. See example below.

I don't want to handle the video on my server. I don't like the idea of my server first receiving a 1GB (example) file and then sending it to YouTube. It would stress my storage capabilities and my bandwidth.

The example below is almost perfect.

The only problem with it is that it requires the user to sign in user their google account.

What I'm wondering is if I somehow can give the client the proper credentials to use MY account to upload the video.

Is that possible? Can I perhaps generate some kind of access token server side and send it to the client so that the client can upload a video to YouTube under my name?

Can it be done without giving the client the ability to do other stuff such as delete videos / edit my account etc?

Example here: https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow users to post content *in your name* without even reviewing it first?

Comment: Baum mit Augen: Good Question, the ideal would be that the videos were uploaded but hidden until reviewed.

Comment: This is not possible; uploading requires users to authenticate with their credentials and upload videos to their own account. Without a user-initiated oAuth token, the upload API is unavailable. You might check out the YouTube Direct Lite app, which has users upload videos to their own accounts but sets up a playlist in your channel (where videos appear on the playlist privately, then you review them, and make them active on your playlist when ready). Users could always delete the videos, but the YouTube Direct Lite app tracks that as well. https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. I'm building something similar at the moment. The general idea is that you store all the secure secret data on the server. (Client secret, refresh token etc)

Then when a client wants to upload a video to youtube, you check (via the server ) if the token has expired (1hr expiration time).

If it has you need to request a new access_token from youtube and then pass that back to the client for them to use.

Just for your info, I am using moment.js for the timekeeping and Meteor.js for the app.

```js
var now = moment();
var result;
if (now.diff(Meteor.settings.youtube.expiration, 'minutes') >= 50) {
  console.log('Getting new access token...')

  var options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    content: "client_secret=" + Meteor.settings.youtube.client_secret + "&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + Meteor.settings.youtube.refresh_token + "&client_id=" + Meteor.settings.youtube.client_id
  }

  try {
    result = HTTP.call("POST", 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', options);
    Meteor.settings.youtube.access_token = result.data.access_token;
    Meteor.settings.youtube.expiration = moment();

    return Meteor.settings.youtube.access_token;
  } catch (e) {
    // Got a network error, time-out or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
    return false;
  }


} else {
  console.log('Returning access token...')
  return Meteor.settings.youtube.access_token;
}
```

Comment: If you provide an access token to the user, he can also list your videos, delete them & so on, can't he?